# Custom filterspecs for auth.user

Tags: django, django-admin

All the techniques I've seen for adding custom filterspecs to the Django admin involve editing models.py (eg [link text](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1051/))

I'm customizing auth.user by registering my own ModelAdmin and would like to add some custom filterspecs. I could fake filterspecs in the template but I'd rather use custom filterspecs. Is there any way I can monkey-patch auth.user.models or achieve this some other way?